# Problem updating CentOS 7, ipa-client conflicts freeipa-client

Tags: centos, yum, software-updates, freeipa

```
[root@Lnx sam]# yum clean all
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Cleaning repos: base epel extras updates
Cleaning up everything
Cleaning up list of fastest mirrors
[root@Lnx sam]# yum repolist enabled
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
base                                                                                                                                                      | 3.6 kB  00:00:00     
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                                      | 3.5 kB  00:00:00     
epel                                                                                                                                                      | 4.3 kB  00:00:00     
extras                                                                                                                                                    | 3.4 kB  00:00:00     
updates                                                                                                                                                   | 3.4 kB  00:00:00     
(1/7): base/7/x86_64/group_gz                                                                                                                             | 156 kB  00:00:00     
(2/7): extras/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                         | 110 kB  00:00:00     
(3/7): epel/x86_64/group_gz                                                                                                                               | 170 kB  00:00:05     
(4/7): updates/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                        | 2.9 MB  00:00:08     
(5/7): base/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                           | 5.7 MB  00:00:18     
(6/7): epel/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                             | 4.8 MB  00:00:24     
(7/7): epel/x86_64/updateinfo                                                                                                                             | 841 kB  00:00:24     
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: centos.uniminuto.edu
 * epel: mirror.cedia.org.ec
 * extras: centos.uniminuto.edu
 * updates: centos.uniminuto.edu
repo id                                                               repo name                                                                                            status
base/7/x86_64                                                         CentOS-7 - Base                                                                                       9,591
epel/x86_64                                                           Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                       12,005
extras/7/x86_64                                                       CentOS-7 - Extras                                                                                       227
updates/7/x86_64                                                      CentOS-7 - Updates                                                                                    1,014
repolist: 22,837
[root@Lnx sam]#
```

I have this:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: libgpod-0.8.3-14.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
           Requires: libplist.so.1()(64bit)
           Removing: libplist-1.10-4.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               libplist.so.1()(64bit)
           Updated By: libplist-1.12-3.el7.x86_64 (base)
              ~libplist.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: libgpod-0.8.3-14.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
           Requires: libusbmuxd.so.2()(64bit)
           Removing: usbmuxd-1.0.8-11.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               libusbmuxd.so.2()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: usbmuxd-1.1.0-1.el7.x86_64 (base)
               Not found
Error: Package: libgpod-0.8.3-14.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
           Requires: libimobiledevice.so.4()(64bit)
           Removing: libimobiledevice-1.1.5-6.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               libimobiledevice.so.4()(64bit)
           Updated By: libimobiledevice-1.2.0-1.el7.x86_64 (base)
              ~libimobiledevice.so.6()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 4 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
ipa-client-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.7.x86_64 has installed conflicts freeipa-client: ipa-client-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.7.x86_64
ipa-client-common-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.7.noarch has installed conflicts freeipa-client-common: ipa-client-common-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.7.noarch
ipa-common-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.7.noarch has installed conflicts freeipa-common: ipa-common-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.7.noarch
ipa-python-compat-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.7.noarch has installed conflicts freeipa-python-compat: ipa-python-compat-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.7.noarch
[root@Lnx sam]# 




[root@Lnx sam]# yum check
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks

ipa-client-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.7.x86_64 has installed conflicts freeipa-client: ipa-client-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.7.x86_64
ipa-client-common-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.7.noarch has installed conflicts freeipa-client-common: ipa-client-common-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.7.noarch
ipa-common-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.7.noarch has installed conflicts freeipa-common: ipa-common-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.7.noarch
ipa-python-compat-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.7.noarch has installed conflicts freeipa-python-compat: ipa-python-compat-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.7.noarch
Error: check all
[root@Lnx sam]#
```

I can't update CentOS 7!

`yum update --skip-broken` appears in infinite loop!

**Some clue?**

Comment: Welcome to UNIX & Linux.  Did you try uninstalling `freeipa-client` first?

Answer (score 3):

Basically I had to uninstall, update, re-install.

After removing freeipa as root with...

```
# yum remove freeipa-client
# yum remove freeipa-common 
# yum remove freeipa-client-common
```

...I still had this conflict on libplist-1.10-4.el7.x86_64. So I used...

```
# yum whatprovides libgpod-0.8.3-14.el7.x86_64
```

...to find out that rythmbox used that too.

```
# yum autoremove libgpod-0.8.3-14.el7.x86_64
```

...removed rythmbox too. I now installed yum priorities which, with hindsight, perhaps that may not have been needed. I suggest skipping that step which should go *here* and carry on with the update and reinstall of uninstalled packages. If the update fails, then yum priorities was needed, instructions are at the end.

Carry on with the update as before

```
# yum update
```

Re-install removed packages

```
# yum install rythmbox
# yum install freeipa*
```

Done.

---

Setting up yum priorities to try and avoid dependency issues.

As is describe in  https://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum/Priorities turn on yum plug-ins by ensuring that /etc/yum.conf contains

```
plugins=1
```

Then run

```
yum install yum-plugin-priorities
```

Check that /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/priorities.conf contains

```
[main]
enabled=1
```

Finally add priorities in /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo

- to Centos*.repo add lines "priority=1"
- to epel*.reo add lines "priority=5"
- to google*.repo add lines "priority=10"